# They spoke with one another or to one another?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. They spoke to one another.
2. They spoke with one another.

Comment: You might want to check this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/866/speak-to-vs-speak-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either the preposition "with" or "to" after the verb 'speak', without any difference in meaning, but the use of 'with' is more common in AE than BE.